Site down after Joomla 5.0.3 update
After Joomla updated to 5.0.3 my site, which also uses jomsocial, stopped functioning. I didn't change a thing and it only broke post update.my home page
my admin screen
I've tried rolling back to an earlier saved version of my site. I have contacted my host provider for assistance. It is still the same issue.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
